# Issue with UTF-/ encoding on csv file for excel

Tags: python, excel, unicode, utf-8

### EDIT:

As suggested special chars are displayed correctly if I use notepad++ to open the csv file. They are displayed correctly too  when I import the csv file into excel.
How can I generate a csv file that is displayed correctly when opened by excel since file importing is not an option for the users

I'm generating a csv file that is being processed using Excel.
Special caracters like 'é' are not displayed properly when the file is opened with excel
[image]

This the poc I'm using to generate the csv file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unicodecsv as csv
import codecs
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
def write_csv(file,headers):


    resultFile =codecs.open(file, "w+", "utf-8")

    #headers=[s.encode('utf-8') for s in headers]
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel',delimiter=";",encoding="utf-8")
    wr.writerow(headers)

    resultFile.close()

headers=[""]
headers.append("Command")
headers.append("Vérification".encode('utf-8'))
write_csv(r"C:\test2.csv",headers)
```

Comment: Did you try to open the file with text editor instead of Excel? If it doesn't give these (Ã©) symbols, you just need to correctly import the file in Excel. Don't double click the file but open a blank document, go to data in the ribbon - import from text - follow dialog instructions. Important in this is to set the correct encoding (after you selected which file to import).

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: In that case take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/911369/change-default-encoding-of-excel-to-utf-8) question

Comment: You do not need the `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` line. Remove it before you break something unexpectedly

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just generate an Excel file instead of that annoying CSV format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue using UTF-8 BOM encoding.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-sig-*-
import unicodecsv as csv
import codecs
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8-sig")
def write_csv(file,headers):


    resultFile =codecs.open(file, "w+", "utf-8-sig")

    #headers=[s.encode('utf-8') for s in headers]
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel',delimiter=";",encoding="utf-8-sig")
    wr.writerow(headers)

    resultFile.close()

headers=[""]
headers.append("Command")
headers.append("Vérification")
write_csv(r"C:\Users\ATHENA-HDA\AppData\Local\Temp\test2.txt",headers)
```

Comment: Overkill.  The `reload(sys)` trick is not needed and can cause errors.  See: [why setdefaultencoding will break code](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).  The `#coding` statement declares the encoding of the source file, so hopefully you saved the source file in UTF-8 w/ BOM.  `csv.writer` doesn't support an `encoding` parameter.  In fact, in Python 2 `csv` doesn't support encodings directly (see `csv` documentation for a workaround).  In Python 3, all that is required is opening the file with an encoding.

Comment: Adding a BOM **is** the solution to opening a CSV correctly in Excel, however.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you were using `unicodecsv`.  My comments about `csv.writer` pertain to the built-in `csv` module.

Comment: example works everywhere but on my Mac's excel app

Comment: That just doesn't work. `myFile = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect="excel", encoding='utf-8-sig')` will result in `ERROR] TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Answer (score 17):

In python3 I just do this:

```
with open(file, "w+", encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
                f.write("Vérification")
```

Pretty simple, right? :)
You can search "utf-8-sig" in
[the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Saved my day! Works perfect good with latin characters, such as ç, á, é, í.

Answer (score 8):

Python 2 solution using `unicodecsv`.  Note that the documentation for `unicodecsv` says the module should be opened in binary mode (`wb`).  Make sure to write Unicode strings.  `#coding` is required to support non-ASCII characters in the source file.  Make sure to save the source file in UTF-8.

```
#coding:utf8
import unicodecsv

with open('test.csv','wb') as f:
    # Manually encode a BOM, utf-8-sig didn't work with unicodecsv
    f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    w = unicodecsv.writer(f,encoding='utf8')
    # Write Unicode strings.
    w.writerow([u'English',u'Chinese'])
    w.writerow([u'American',u'美国人'])
    w.writerow([u'Chinese',u'中国人'])
```

Python 3 solution.  `#coding` is optional here because it defaults to UTF-8.  Just make sure to save the source file in UTF-8.  `unicodecsv` is no longer required.  The built-in `csv` works correctly.  `csv` documentation says to open the file with `newline=''`.

```
#coding:utf8
import csv

with open('test.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    # Write Unicode strings.
    w.writerow([u'English',u'Chinese'])
    w.writerow([u'American',u'美国人'])
    w.writerow([u'Chinese',u'中国人'])
```